# Identify outliers in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

Current data frame consists of numerical values.
I am identifying outliers in my dataframe column by column, 
can I identify the outliers in the column at once and remove them in one go?
Right now I am changing the values to NA

My Code:

```
    quantiles<-tapply(var1,names,quantile) 
    minq <- sapply(names, function(x) quantiles[[x]]["25%"])
    maxq <- sapply(names, function(x) quantiles[[x]]["75%"])
    var1[var1<minq | var1>maxq] <- NA
```

**Data.**

Data posted by the OP in a comment in `dput` format.

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Var1 = c(100.2, 110, 200, 456, 120000), 
var2 = c(NA, 4545L, 45465L, 44422L, 250000L), 
var3 = c(NA, 210000L, 91500L, 215000L, 250000L), 
var4 = c(0.983, 0.44, 0.983, 0.78, 2.23)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide a small data.frame and the expected output ?. It is important to provide with examples to make the questions reproducible. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the outliers"? Do you want to delete rows that contain the outlier?

Comment: Yes, I do want to remove the outliers

Comment: You should post the data **in the question**, not as a comment. Also, why not `na.omit`, `na.exclude` or `complete.cases` after changing them to `NA`?

Comment: This is subset of my dataframe, there are around 15 columns, How can I identify the outliers in one go

Answer (score 0):

The following removes the outliers from the dataframe, but the result is a *list*, not a dataframe, since the resulting vectors are not all of the same length.

```
df2 <- lapply(df1, function(x){
  qq <- quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE)
  x[!is.na(x) & qq[1] <= x & x <= qq[2]]
})
```

**Edit**

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634463/identifying-outliers-using-quartile-range) by the same [@user11368874](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11368874/user11368874), the code below is inspired in the first code above and answers that second question.

```
df3 <- df1
df3[] <- lapply(df1, function(x){
  qq <- quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE)
  is.na(x) <-  x < qq[1] | x > qq[2]
  x
})

df3
#  Var1  var2   var3  var4
#1   NA    NA     NA 0.983
#2  110    NA 210000    NA
#3  200 45465     NA 0.983
#4  456 44422 215000 0.780
#5   NA    NA     NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function tests, which values in columns are outside of Tukey's fences (outliers below and above the 1st and the 3rd quartile). Then, depending on the user preference, the function removes all rows that contain any value with an outlier or replaces the outliers with `NA`.

```
outlier.out <- function(dat, q = c(0.25, 0.75), out = TRUE){
    # create a place for identification of outliers
    tests <- matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(dat), nrow = nrow(dat))
    # test, which cells contain outliers, ignoring existing NA values
    for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){
        qq <- quantile(dat[, i], q, na.rm = TRUE)
        tests[, i] <- sapply(dat[, i] < qq[1] | dat[, i] > qq[2], isTRUE)
    }
    if(out){
        # removes lines with outliers
        dat <- dat[!apply(tests, 1, FUN = any, na.rm = TRUE) ,]
    } else {
        # replaces outliers with NA
        dat[tests] <- NA
    }
    return(dat)
}

outlier.out(df1)
#   Var1  var2   var3 var4
# 4  456 44422 215000 0.78


outlier.out(df1, out = FALSE)
#   Var1  var2   var3  var4
# 1   NA    NA     NA 0.983
# 2  110    NA 210000    NA
# 3  200 45465     NA 0.983
# 4  456 44422 215000 0.780
# 5   NA    NA     NA    NA
```